# Windows 10: Microphone not working in browsers, working in Zoom (Windows application)

Tags: windows-10, audio, browser, microphone, google-meet

I have a Windows 10 Home Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.1304) system in which the microphone works in Zoom (the Windows application), but not in Google Meet (ie, https://meet.google.com in a browser). Within Google Meet in the browser, the other side can see us, but not hear us. We are able to hear and see them properly.

1. Have tried in Chrome, Firefox and Opera - no change.
2. In Chrome, the pressing the down arrow just before the URL shows the microphone permission to be enabled.
3. In chrome://settings/ -> Privacy and security -> Site Settings -> Permissions: Microphone shows 3 options:

> ```
> Default - Microphone (Conexant SmartAudio HD)
> Communications - Microphone (Conexant SmartAudio HD)
> Microphone (Conexant SmartAudio HD)
>
> The first one is selected.
> ```

4. In chrome://settings/ -> Privacy and security -> Site Settings -> Permissions: Microphone, https://meet.google.com:443 is listed, and within that, Microphone is set to Allow

How can I get the microphone to work properly within the browser or how can I diagnose this further?

Comment: You should probably start by updating Windows. Your build is very old.

Comment: In the Google Meet menu *Settings > Audio tab > Microphone*, is the correct microphone selected?